# cck fieldgroup tabs appear but all fields in one tab

Tags: entities

I am using cck fieldgroup tabs to group various fieldsets under different tabs and I want them to appear in tabs to anonymous user.

Somehow the tabs are not working. The tabs are all there sitting above but all the fields within each fieldset are all shown on the same page and the tab links work as if they are internal links for the same page. You click on any link and you are moved down to the fields in that fieldset on the same page.

I looked into the generated page in firebug and it came out that the classes responsible for generation and grouping of tabs are all wrong in the div and ul tags. when I changed them to the correct ones using firebug , they all looked fine in browser.

Now I dont know how are these classes put into div tags in the backend so that i can rectify it. Can someone help please.?

Comment: anyone please????

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions to ensure the fields are available to the anonymous users.

Comment: I dont think its a permissions issue because it should at least be visible in tabs to admin, but thats not the case. Isn't it?